# Navigation inside vue component with vue-native-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-native

The [vue-native-router](https://vue-native.io/docs/vue-native-router.html) docs provide a good example about how to implement a navigation to switch between screens, which works so far in my little demo app that I'm trying to build to get a grasp about how things work.

The basics that are required to navigate from one screen to another, inside a screen vue template, are so far:

```
<template>
    <view class="o-container">
        <button title="ChangeView" :on-press="goToMyNewFancyView" />
    </view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        navigation: {
            type: Object
        }
    },
    methods: {
        goToMyNewFancyView() {
            this.navigation.navigate('MyNewFancyView');
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

(I've skipped the main setup of the `StackNavigator` as this is completely the same as in the docs and not really helpful for this question, see TJ Weems answer).

My aim is now to have a list of components that display a title and a description. By clicking on the component, the screen should be changed to the component's detail view. Thus, I tried to implement the same for my component:

```
<template>
    <view>
        <text>This is a component.</text>

        <button title="show more" :on-press="show" />
    </view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        navigation: {
            type: Object
        }
    },
    methods: {
        show() {
            this.navigation.navigate('MyShowView');
        }
    }
};
```

However, `this.navigation` is `undefined` inside the vue component. Somehow I don't understand the connections here and could not find anything relatable that would explain this. I'm also not sure if this is the correct way, or if navigation should happen outside of the component at all.

**How would one implement a link from a component that is a teaser for a thing to the actual detail screen?**

---

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "expo": "^32.0.0",
  "react": "16.5.0",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-0",
  "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
  "vue-native-core": "0.0.8",
  "vue-native-helper": "0.0.10",
  "vue-native-router": "0.0.1-alpha.3",
  "vue-native-scripts": "0.0.14"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the params you can use the navigation options. First add some data:

```
methods: {
        show() {
            this.navigation.navigate('MyShowView', { myData : 'Hi' });
        }
    }
```

And then your MyShowView, get the data as follows:

```
this.navigation.getParam("myData");
```

Wherever you need.

Found this in [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) and [vue-native-router](https://vue-native.io/docs/vue-native-router.html#Moving-between-screens) docs

Answer (score 0):

Did you do this part? or something similar..

```
<script>
import { StackNavigator } from "vue-native-router";
import HomeScreen from "../src/screens/homeScreen.vue";
import DetailsScreen from "../src/screens/detailsScreen.vue";
const AppNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);
export default {
    components: { AppNavigation }
}
</script>
```

Instance of component

```
<template>
  <app-navigation></app-navigation>
</template>
```

Comment: Yes, that's the part I omitted as described. Navigating from one screen view to another works, it just doesn't work inside a component.

Answer (score 0):

> My aim is now to have a list of components that display a title and a
>   description. By clicking on the component, the screen should be
>   changed to the component's detail view. Thus, I tried to implement the
>   same for my component:

Why couldnt you do something like this?

```
StackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Detail: {
      screen: DetailScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Detail Screen',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
      },
    },
})
```

using the `navigationOptions` to add a title and description to your list of routing components, you would have this data available to you to display.

each router component would still render the view or screen you have associated with that link.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. My question is "how can I get the `this.navigation` part in my component, which is `undefined`, in order to be able to navigate within my component. I'm not asking about how to update the title of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for mine. Try to change the button to

`<button title="show more" :on-press="show" :navigation="this.props.navigation" />`